# Leray spectral sequence from hypercohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, spectral-sequences

*Context: Deligne, Theorie de Hodge II, section 1.4.8.*

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between spaces; $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$, and $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}^{\bullet}$ a resolution of $\mathcal{F}$ by a complex of $f_{*}$-acyclic sheaves.

The canonical filtration of $f_{*}\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}$ is defined in the reference above as follows:

$$(\tau_{\leq p} f_{*}\mathcal{F}^{\bullet})^n = \begin{cases}
      f_{*}\mathcal{F}^n & \text{if }\ n<p \\
      \text{Ker}(d) & \text{if }\ n = p \\
      0 & \text{if } n>p
    \end{cases}$$

***Question 0:*** Should the right hand side of the preceding equation be changed by replacing "$p$" with "$-p$" everywhere?

Deligne writes the hypercohomology spectral sequence of $(f_{*}\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},\tau_{\leq p})$ as:
$$E_1^{p,q}= H^{2p+q}(Y,R^{-p}f_{*}\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,\mathcal{F})$$

***Question 1:*** Where did this latter spectral sequence come from? Specifically, how is it the hypercohomology spectral sequence of $(f_{*}\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},\tau_{\leq p})$ ? Assuming the correct answer to Question 0 is "Yes", I thought the hypercohomology spectral sequence should read:

$$R^{p+q}\Gamma(\text{Gr}^p f_{*}\mathcal{F}^{\bullet}) = H^{p+q}(Y,\mathcal{H}^{-p}(f_{*}\mathcal{F}^{\bullet})) = H^{p+q}(Y,R^{-p}f_{*}\mathcal{F}) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,\mathcal{F})$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really a comment, but too long to write as one. Deligne leaves some steps to the reader. The filtration $\tau$ is  increasing. To write the standard spectral sequence, we need to switch signs (as you seem to surmise) to get a decreasing filtration. Let me write $T^p = \tau_{\le -p}$. Then we have
$$E_1^{p+q} = H^{p+q}(Y, Gr_T^p \mathbb{R} f_*\mathcal{F})$$
converging to what you wrote. This simplifies to 
$$H^{p+q}(Y, R^{-p} f_*\mathcal{F}[p])=H^{2p+q}(Y, R^{-p} f_*\mathcal{F})$$
So all is well.